# What is the source for poet Kambar's description of Rama's physical features in Kamba Ramayanam?

Tags: ramayana

Kamba Ramayanam is the most famous Tamil version of the epic Ramayana.

Sometime back, I was told that Valmiki does not describe Rama's looks anywhere in his original Ramayana.

Whereas, poet Kambar, who had Valmiki Ramayanam for the basis of his work in tamil, is said to have described Sri Rama's beauty in detail.

What is the source for this description by Kambar? Or was it divine revelation for him?

Comment: Kambar was also a great saint poet of Classical Tamil Era.  As a devotee of Vishnu, his description of Sri Rama's beauty and personality is likely to have been envisioned.  His description is much more detailed than Narada's description to Maharishi Valmiki, enumerated in Sarga 1 of the Bala Kaanda in Valmiki Ramayana.